# Implementation details of Python multiprocessing fork vs spawn

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

According to the multiprocessing documentation on [picklability](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#all-start-methods), it states

> Picklability
>
> > Ensure that the arguments to the methods of proxies are picklable.
>
> More picklability
>
> > Ensure that all arguments to Process.**init**() are picklable. Also, if you subclass Process then make sure that instances will be picklable when the Process.start method is called.

I think it basically means that whatever is sent through arguments of `Process` will be pickled/unpickled.

But in *Better to inherit than pickle/unpickle* session, it states

> When using the spawn or forkserver start methods many types from multiprocessing need to be picklable so that child processes can use them. However, one should generally avoid sending shared objects to other processes using pipes or queues. Instead you should arrange the program so that a process which needs access to a shared resource created elsewhere can inherit it from an ancestor process.

I conducted the experiment which shows the output `Read successfully.`.

```py
def read_dataset(dataset, window):
    return dataset.read(window=window)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mp.set_start_method("fork")
    with rasterio.open(Path("test.tiff").absolute()) as dataset:
        window = Window(col_off=0, row_off=0, width=100, height=100)
        p1 = mp.Process(target=read_dataset, args=(dataset, window))
        p1.start()
        p1.join()
    print("Read successfully.")
```

But when changing to `mp.set_start_method("spawn")`, it shows the error below.

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 88, in <module>
    p1.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py", line 284, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py", line 32, in __init__
    super().__init__(process_obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 19, in __init__
    self._launch(process_obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py", line 47, in _launch
    reduction.dump(process_obj, fp)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "stringsource", line 2, in rasterio._io.DatasetReaderBase.__reduce_cython__
TypeError: self._hds cannot be converted to a Python object for pickling
```

My question is the following.
When a child process is generated with `fork`, the variable is inherited instead of pickled/unpickled. But when a child process is generated with `spawn`, then the arguments are sent through pickling/unpickling. Where can I find such implementation detail? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[multiprocessing context](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/multiprocessing/context.py#L270)

[popen fork](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7fc39a21cb85163a456eab91b52e5fe85e7f7e3e/Lib/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py#L66)

[spawn fork](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7fc39a21cb85163a456eab91b52e5fe85e7f7e3e/Lib/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py#L58)

`fork` shares a value in memory and starts it.

`spawn` is implemented by creating a cmd for the source code and sharing some variables through a `pipe`.

If you edit and save the source code just before spawning, you can get the result of the modified code.